# Writing to a Spring-bound Map in Velocity

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, velocity

I'm trying to iterate over a Map in Velocity using Spring MVC and creating a FORM from it. This works fine, but I can't get the values to save back to the map.

Here's the template:

```
<form method="POST" action="save">
  #foreach($item in $data.data.entrySet())
    $item.key
    <input name="data.data['$item.key']" value="$data.data[$item.key]" />
    <br />
  #end

  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and the backing bean looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {
        DataBean data = new DataBean();
        data.addItem("name", "name123");
        data.addItem("firstname", "firstname345");

        model.addAttribute("data", data);
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@Validated DataBean data) {
        System.out.println(data.getData());
        return "home";
    }

}
```

Displaying the form looks fine, but the map is always empty on submit.

Any ideas? Thanks!